# Drawable resources: Failed to re-package resources, see the console for details

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

In my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have these lines:

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon"
             android:resource="@drawable/front_icon" />
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.vr.icon_background"
             android:resource="@drawable/back_icon" />
```

These lines specify icon files to use for VR app icons, and [are required for Daydream](https://developers.google.com/vr/distribute/daydream/publishing-requirements#PB-P2). Unfortunately, the instructions on *where* these files go is unclear:

> Note: Assets for VR should be placed inside the nodpi/ resource directory to ensure display density scaling is not applied on load.

Where in my Unity project am I supposed to place these files?

The error when I try to build is

> Failed to re-package resources. See the console for details.

With this in the console (error trimmed from its massive 4000 lines down to the relevant information):

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>
> ```
> stderr[
> AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name
>   (at 'resource' with value '@drawable/front_icon').
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name
>   (at 'resource' with value '@drawable/back_icon').
> ]
> ```

The manifest file is located in the `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory and there is a `res` directory at `Assets/Plugins/Android/res`

I have tried:

```
res/drawable
res/drawable/nodpi
res/nodpi/drawable
res/nodpi
```

With the front_icon.png and back_icon.png inside that folder. None of these have worked.

Comment: Took me the better part of a day to find the answer to my specific question, then another to figure out if this question had ever been addressed on SO before, which it had not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost correct. The folder you want is

```
res/drawable-nodpi
```

You can find the documentation on how Android specifies these folders [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), which I got to by first finding [this page on providing resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), searching for "nodpi", and clicking the "See Supporting Multiple Screens for more information" link, and then just having to find the right section.

There was a link under the heading "How to Support Multiple Screens" near the top of the page ("The configuration qualifiers (described in detail below)") that took me to the right section while skimming the page's content.

> To use a configuration qualifier:
>
> 1. Create a new directory in your project's `res/` directory and name it using the format: `<resources_name>-<qualifier>`
>
>    - `<resources_name>` is the standard resource name (such as drawable or layout).
>    - `<qualifier>` is a configuration qualifier from table 1, below, specifying the screen configuration for which these resources are to be used (such as `hdpi` or `xlarge`).
> 2. You can use more than one `<qualifier>` at a time—simply separate each qualifier with a dash.
>
>    - Save the appropriate configuration-specific resources in this new directory. The resource files must be named exactly the same as the default resource files.
>
> For example, `xlarge` is a configuration qualifier for extra-large screens. When you append this string to a resource directory name (such as `layout-xlarge`), it indicates to the system that these resources are to be used on devices that have an extra-large screen.

I definitely think that from a Unity developer standpoint this information does feel hidden, as it's an Android thing and the relevant page you were starting from didn't include a link back to the supporting documentation, as it assumed you were already familiar with specifying other resources (which Unity handles automatically for you).